# errors from Windows clients accessing printer via Samba despite CUPS working

Tags: samba, cups, active-directory

On CentOS 6.4 (newdc), I have CUPS 1.4.2-50.el6_4.5 installed, can access its web interface.  There I set up our main shared printer, an OCE Imagistics cm2520, and successfully printed a test page.

With SerNet Samba 4.0.9 on the same box configured every which example way I could find, I cannot seem to get it to the point where double-clicking the printer in Windows (W2K3, OLDDC) opens up the print queue (as it does from \olddc).  The closest I get, by manually defining the printer in smb.conf, is that it shows up in \newdc in Windows Explorer, but double-clicking the BackOfficeCopier printer gives this error:

```
---------------------------
Printers
---------------------------
Operation could not be completed. Either the printer name was typed incorrectly, or the specified printer has lost its connection to the server.  For more information, click Help.
---------------------------
OK   Help
---------------------------
```

If I double-click the "printers" share, I get:

```
---------------------------
\\newdc
---------------------------
\\newdc\printers is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

Incorrect function.

---------------------------
OK
---------------------------
```

Neither of these causes an entry to appear in log.samba.  However, double-clicking on Printers and Faxes shows me a folder containing just "Add Printer" and generates this log entry in log.samba:

```
[2013/08/23 09:18:39.921226,  0] ../source4/smb_server/smb/service.c:127(make_connection)
  make_connection: couldn't find service ::{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2013/08/23 09:18:39.935896,  0] ../source4/rpc_server/spoolss/dcesrv_spoolss.c:1189(dcesrv_spoolss_RemoteFindFirstPrinterChangeNotifyEx)
  unable to call back to \\OLDDC
[2013/08/23 09:18:39.952321,  0] ../source4/rpc_server/spoolss/dcesrv_spoolss.c:1189(dcesrv_spoolss_RemoteFindFirstPrinterChangeNotifyEx)
  unable to call back to \\OLDDC
```

If I then try "Add Printer" and click Next, my only choice is the top one and there are no ports listed.  Trying "Next" again at that point just gives:

```
---------------------------
Add Printer Wizard
---------------------------
Operation could not be completed.
---------------------------
OK
---------------------------
```

About the first error, the queue name in CUPS is OCE, and in smb.conf I have this:

```
[global]
        workgroup = MYDOMAIN
        realm = mydomain.lan
        netbios name = NEWDC
        server role = active directory domain controller
        server services = rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, smb, dns
        allow dns updates = true
        dns forwarder = 192.168.1.1
#        dns recursive queries = yes
        dcerpc endpoint servers = epmapper, wkssvc, rpcecho, samr, netlogon, lsarpc, spoolss, drsuapi, dssetup, unixinfo, browser, eventlog6, backupkey, dnsserver, winreg, srvsvc
#       dcerpc endpoint servers = winreg srvsvc
        load printers = yes
        printing = cups
printcap name = cups

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/mydomain.lan/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No

[printers]
     comment = All Printers
     path = /var/spool/samba/
        guest ok = Yes
     browseable = Yes
     read only = No
     printable = Yes
        create mask = 0700

[print$]
     comment = Point and Print Printer Drivers
     path = /var/lib/samba/printing
     read only = No

[BackOfficeCopier]
     path = /var/spool/samba/
     browseable = yes
     printable = yes
     printer name = OCE

[mytest]
        path = /home/srv/samba-test-share
        read only = No
```

As far as ACL goes for the second error, etc.:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/
...
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root   root   4096 Aug 15 18:10 samba

$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/samba/
...
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root    4096 Aug 22 22:19 printing
```

I copied everything from \olddc\print$ to \newdc\print$ before chmodding printing back to 755.

I followed the HOWTO.  CUPS set up my printer correctly.  Permissions seem to be right.  What am I missing?